# Regex Criação Personalizada

Tags: regex, validação

Ola,

Conheço bem pouco de regex e preciso criar um que valide o resultado de um barcode, já usei vários sites, mas como não tenho conhecimento não consigo fazer, alguém sabe criar um regex para validar a estrutura abaixo.

estrutura
FKDOC0000000000000000
Sempre inicia com FKDOC Maiúsculo e deve conter 16 dígitos

Obrigado

Comment: 16 digitos no total? ou 16 digitos apos o `FKDOC`?

Comment: Recomendo usar o [tools lymas](http://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php) para testar suas regex, la também tem vários exemplos úteis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar essa expressão: `^FKDOC\d{16}$`. Signfica que vai capturar no início da string por `FKDOC` seguido de 16 dígitos (0-9).